# Typescript conditional types seem to allow null

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

Given this example of conditional type:

```
type MyType = 'Number' | 'String';

interface Test<T extends MyType> {
  bar: T extends 'Number' ? 25 : '25'
}
```

If I try to:

```
const test: Test<'Number'> = {bar: null}
```

I get no complains, this seems to be valid Typescript. However, when I hover over `bar` I get a popup saying `(property) Test<"Number">.bar: 25`
 which seems to mean that TS has understood the type correct.

Why do I get no error assigning in such a way then? How can I fix that?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen it doesn't matter, it's an illustration... Here it was intended to show an example union type. Could be an enum, or any other union type, won't change anything, it's not about `number | string`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just enable the [compiler option](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) `--strict` or `--strictNullChecks`.